# Conditional Probablity - post event

Tags: probability

5 black balls and 11 white balls are put in a bag. 3 balls are taken out. If the fourth ball is black, what is the probability that 3 first balls are white ?

Can we apply conditional probability here and find probability? As defined, conditional probability is  probability of an event if another event has already happened.

Please help to solve this.

Comment: One way to solve this would be to chart out the probability of each of the 4 ways the fourth ball could be black.  The first set of three could be 3 whites 2 whites, 1 white, 0 whites.  Each one of them leads to a different probability of the 4th ball being black.  Then take the probability for the 3 white option divided by the sum of all 4.

Comment: A much easier and more efficient way is to argue that there is a bijection (i.e. no real difference) between picking out the first three balls and then the fourth, versus picking out the "fourth" ball intially, and then picking out the other three after.  Thinking of it as the equivalent problem of "if you first picked out a black ball, what is the probability that the next three are white", the solution should be much clearer.

Comment: Let $W$ be the event first three are white, and $B$ be the event fourth is black.  We want $\Pr(A|B)$ which by definition is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$. Now we need to find two probabilities. The one at the bottom is easier than it may look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If the fourth ball is black, what is the probability that 3 first balls are white ?
>
> Can we apply conditional probability here and find probability?

Yes, using conditional probability, $P(W \mid B) = \frac{P(W)P(B\mid W)}{P(B)}$ ( Bayes' Theorem )

$P(W)$ is the probability of selecting 3 of 11 white balls out of all 16 balls.

$P(B)$ is the probability of selecting 1 of 5 black balls out of all 16 balls.

$P(B\mid W)$ is the probability of selecting 1 of 5 black balls out of the 13 balls that remain after having selected 3 of the 11 white balls.

$P(W\mid B)$ is the probability of selecting 3 of 11 white balls out of all 16 when given that one of the black balls is *reserved* to be selected latter.

**However,** it is much easier to *not bother* with finding the first three probabilities and just calculate the fourth (the one we want) directly.

Go back to basics.  Never forget the basics.

Under the given condition, that one black ball is reserved for the fourth place:

- **Favoured Space**: To select 3 of the 11 white balls into the first three places.
- **Total (Conditioned) Space**: To select any 3 of the 15 balls that are not the reserved ball.

Count the ways to do the former, and the later, divide, and calculate.

---

**Remark** The 'trick' here is that the order of events doesn't affect the conditional probability calculation. The conditional probability that the first three balls will be white given that the fourth ball will be black is the same as the conditional probability that draws 8, 10, and 14 will be white when given that draw 12 will be black.